# JavaScript import falls out of scope?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, import, scope

I have a React + redux app where the following code fails because `type` seems to never get assigned a value, even though I can see with the debugger that it passes through line #56.

It looks like `AppConstants` is falling out of scope somehow - because when I hover over that variable in the debugger - I don't get a popup with it's value. However, it seems to log to console just fine.

When I change line #56 to `type = 'banana'` it is assigned correctly. Which also leads me to believe it's a problem with `AppConstants`.

I'm not sure what I am missing with regards to JavaScript scoping.

Code:

```
// app.constants.js
const CONSTANTS = {
    GET_TENANT_REQUEST: 'GET_TENANT_REQUEST',
    GET_TENANT_SUCCESS: 'GET_TENANT_SUCCESS',
    GET_TENANT_FAILURE: 'GET_TENANT_FAILURE',
    // ...
}

export default CONSTANTS
```

```
// main.js

import AppConstants from './app.constants'

const createAppActions = ({ config, dispatch }) => {
    // ... other code

    const failure = payload => {
        let type
        if (payload && payload.method) {
            console.log("APP CONSTS", AppConstants)
            type = AppConstants[`${payload.method}_FAILIRE`]
        } else {
            throw new Error("FAILURE: No method found in payload", payload)
        }
        console.log("TYPE", type)
        return { type, error: payload.errorMsg, serviceName: payload.serviceName }
    }

    const getSomethingData = () => {
        // ....
        dispatch(failure({ method: 'GET_TENANT' }))
    }

    // ... other code

    return {
        // ...
        getSomethingData,
    }
}

export default createAppActions
```

### Debugger Screenshot (execution is currently paused at line #61):

[image: debugger screenshot]

### Console Output:

[image: console output]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out...I have a typo on line 56...it should be `_FAILURE` and not `_FAILIRE`...

Let this be a lesson to not string interpolate constants...